# Xamarin iOS programmatically add navigation bar to table view

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, xamarin

I don't want to use a storyboard. I want to programmatically add a navigation bar to a Table View. I got one Xib file with a Table View but the rest is all done by code.

How can I add a navigation bar and customize it?

I tried the following but that doesn't work:

```
UINavigationBar navBar = new UINavigationBar ();
View.AddSubview (navBar);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Table View be in the UINavigationView not the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Create an instance of the UIViewController, representing the necessary screen.

2 Pass the instance of the UIViewController as a parameter to the constructor of the UINavigationController.

3 Set the windows root view controller to the instance of the UINavigationController to show the necessary screen:

```
 [Register ("AppDelegate")] 
 public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate {

     UIWindow window;   
     CompanyController cc;

     public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
     {     
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);   
        cc = new CompanyController ();
        // If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:                   
        window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController (cc);
        // make the window visible     
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;   
      } 
  }
```

more detail http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/01/01/xamarin-how-to.aspx